# Devise showing user not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and [angular2-token](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token). But Devise is not registering that a user is signed in.

I have a create definition that returns the current_user and the user_signed_in? status:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /movies
  def create
    if Movie.exists?(title: movie_params[:title])
      render json: { body: 'Movie already exists', status: 400 }
    else
      @user = current_user
      @signed_in = user_signed_in?
      render json: {
          user: @user, status: @signed_in
      }
    end

  end

  def movie_params
    # whitelist params
    params.permit(:title, :created_by, :id)
  end

end
```

When I run my application this returns `user: null, status: false`.

The applicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

The strange thing is that I do have a user signed in. This is what the Rails log shows when I reload the page:

```
Started GET "/auth/validate_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-07 09:15:03 +0200
Started GET "/auth/validate_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-07 09:15:03 +0200
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as JSON
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as JSON
Parameters: {"token_validation"=>{}}
Parameters: {"token_validation"=>{}}
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`uid` = 'peter@cleanpixel.nl' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`uid` = 'peter@cleanpixel.nl' LIMIT 1
   (1.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `tokens` = '{\"dj9nsHh0XTBTnxaBT3kyiw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$otdEoY.3ATpQtcMPvOIxkeJKjcn4hHG.OhOAa5hN/haKjoD8mdEHK\",\"expiry\":1500566765,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gWHnaLi.MQCrSpc3uqZI.uR6dsbSv3.OAbA/VmFQFOSwYy.ilzbSy\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:06:05.349+02:00\"},\"Zb9n6Xsuv8uDoz0UgREIvA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$WsH4tTHx3t7olJwdNNekG.zxCo2.5CRPYvTJQN1muKZnBeKD3z8Eq\",\"expiry\":1500569836,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$cK1y.pzug.PpTi53/bxMG.A.h8idbngy1G4G07fke1YKCCBqmxBXK\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:57:16.971+02:00\"},\"cqBp_VyXAgnwQaboLddNqA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aHpZo34C3BOgBCRuMZXA8u8Dm9eQbaZBncMfAUExcJnSzBgXoHWta\",\"expiry\":1500567653,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$N9la9pzAkmJotIf/nVmx6uOmHVBhYjagMTKhCb/52hVFhlwhbotz2\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:20:55.382+02:00\"},\"-1YucaseQui9xTM8joV1bA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ZTYVkIcPjl7VDi45RkkB3uvZLM8I5GYgNnm1Go602T4AUP40TWmIK\",\"expiry\":1500570282,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$Blv8cg7Q0Nq2l9mYoWpDe./W4Bmqw6Tadvh0rb63PQTJ9O8BbWBD.\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:04:42.416+02:00\"},\"r37dOyCTPEPPF0E3n4MJAw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$gb8ERl211K2HcHe6X1SX1ex2yQ4L9JqJQF5dLM.faEUeIgW0v1Sma\",\"expiry\":1500573270,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$ol47NlxNVlWTOc6LuOQHNuaFJOpxO/I8huGuB/1wwiFT3XjCNFKPW\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:54:30.343+02:00\"},\"7FWoXqZgN7WDmkOIgonMDA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$K4gLINjrtFvEbmGG9wM88OfMbJF3y4mw39U8Y/io9awRTBtLNhyTa\",\"expiry\":1500573600,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gucXe2txI3XT5bCfqP5QfegS.c.DAJLAzemgxm1YSbyGXutt01b02\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:00:01.178+02:00\"},\"pUk1lCvCOmCyxfFKv4Tmnw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$U7RL54MKDFPQCq/R7uhjDeafKtqpj9X1zCAk1kWmIjYkWUeaCpfcS\",\"expiry\":1500574025,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$p0Unq1sHVowseikwok7HqOVw/wAry/K1RZHUrzL0.OMdVQ1T.cYPS\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:07:05.733+02:00\"},\"Zpq95Nuc5UOP6PEK4nDCjQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$C5f/nxd35s/6HmewsWmMU.aB4GHn7Hh6NTJEWR3xxzAwA4iHKDZlC\",\"expiry\":1500575385,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$yjQGp/F.dHBipka.DHheaeSHhMDyPVukLhxhiE4V79BsJrytIDfOi\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:29:45.673+02:00\"},\"2vGGRC7gOCFTBiYSkMCfXQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ykxrUsRX0yZOtLW03cbqyezhVQ4fqnLHBrVIgilIaxhp0d8hqCE0m\",\"expiry\":1500618218,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$dEf3s9O.Upz4cG0xAwEOC.Axlw70Xm9fsy9f2UP5iqffGT1BPLEze\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T08:23:38.253+02:00\"},\"kkuI52Vq05TOCSVBgHGWHA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$XDPo.nKeRj.blboiVey8u.sh7vlubmRo5k/B86l5AvL3ZJw.0yjhG\",\"expiry\":1500621303,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$RkvthXkouoosD2l3OVFNqetvlfG686Ltac1TAlO9to0SMOpSgpKue\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T09:15:03.317+02:00\"}}', `updated_at` = '2017-07-07 07:15:03' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
  User Load (67.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
   (3.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 137ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)


  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `tokens` = '{\"dj9nsHh0XTBTnxaBT3kyiw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$otdEoY.3ATpQtcMPvOIxkeJKjcn4hHG.OhOAa5hN/haKjoD8mdEHK\",\"expiry\":1500566765,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gWHnaLi.MQCrSpc3uqZI.uR6dsbSv3.OAbA/VmFQFOSwYy.ilzbSy\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:06:05.349+02:00\"},\"Zb9n6Xsuv8uDoz0UgREIvA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$WsH4tTHx3t7olJwdNNekG.zxCo2.5CRPYvTJQN1muKZnBeKD3z8Eq\",\"expiry\":1500569836,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$cK1y.pzug.PpTi53/bxMG.A.h8idbngy1G4G07fke1YKCCBqmxBXK\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:57:16.971+02:00\"},\"cqBp_VyXAgnwQaboLddNqA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aHpZo34C3BOgBCRuMZXA8u8Dm9eQbaZBncMfAUExcJnSzBgXoHWta\",\"expiry\":1500567653,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$N9la9pzAkmJotIf/nVmx6uOmHVBhYjagMTKhCb/52hVFhlwhbotz2\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:20:55.382+02:00\"},\"-1YucaseQui9xTM8joV1bA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ZTYVkIcPjl7VDi45RkkB3uvZLM8I5GYgNnm1Go602T4AUP40TWmIK\",\"expiry\":1500570282,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$Blv8cg7Q0Nq2l9mYoWpDe./W4Bmqw6Tadvh0rb63PQTJ9O8BbWBD.\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:04:42.416+02:00\"},\"r37dOyCTPEPPF0E3n4MJAw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$gb8ERl211K2HcHe6X1SX1ex2yQ4L9JqJQF5dLM.faEUeIgW0v1Sma\",\"expiry\":1500573270,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$ol47NlxNVlWTOc6LuOQHNuaFJOpxO/I8huGuB/1wwiFT3XjCNFKPW\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:54:30.343+02:00\"},\"7FWoXqZgN7WDmkOIgonMDA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$K4gLINjrtFvEbmGG9wM88OfMbJF3y4mw39U8Y/io9awRTBtLNhyTa\",\"expiry\":1500573600,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gucXe2txI3XT5bCfqP5QfegS.c.DAJLAzemgxm1YSbyGXutt01b02\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:00:01.178+02:00\"},\"pUk1lCvCOmCyxfFKv4Tmnw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$U7RL54MKDFPQCq/R7uhjDeafKtqpj9X1zCAk1kWmIjYkWUeaCpfcS\",\"expiry\":1500574025,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$p0Unq1sHVowseikwok7HqOVw/wAry/K1RZHUrzL0.OMdVQ1T.cYPS\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:07:05.733+02:00\"},\"Zpq95Nuc5UOP6PEK4nDCjQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$C5f/nxd35s/6HmewsWmMU.aB4GHn7Hh6NTJEWR3xxzAwA4iHKDZlC\",\"expiry\":1500575385,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$yjQGp/F.dHBipka.DHheaeSHhMDyPVukLhxhiE4V79BsJrytIDfOi\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:29:45.673+02:00\"},\"2vGGRC7gOCFTBiYSkMCfXQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ykxrUsRX0yZOtLW03cbqyezhVQ4fqnLHBrVIgilIaxhp0d8hqCE0m\",\"expiry\":1500618218,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$dEf3s9O.Upz4cG0xAwEOC.Axlw70Xm9fsy9f2UP5iqffGT1BPLEze\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T08:23:38.253+02:00\"},\"kkuI52Vq05TOCSVBgHGWHA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$XDPo.nKeRj.blboiVey8u.sh7vlubmRo5k/B86l5AvL3ZJw.0yjhG\",\"expiry\":1500621303,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$RkvthXkouoosD2l3OVFNqetvlfG686Ltac1TAlO9to0SMOpSgpKue\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T09:15:03.323+02:00\"}}' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 142ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 71.1ms)
```

And this is what Rails logs when I log in my user:

```
Started OPTIONS "/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-07 09:22:44 +0200
Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-07 09:22:44 +0200
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"email"=>"peter@cleanpixel.nl", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"peter@cleanpixel.nl", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :session
Unpermitted parameter: :session
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (BINARY email = 'peter@cleanpixel.nl' AND provider='email') ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameter: :session
Unpermitted parameter: :session
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `tokens` = '{\"dj9nsHh0XTBTnxaBT3kyiw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$otdEoY.3ATpQtcMPvOIxkeJKjcn4hHG.OhOAa5hN/haKjoD8mdEHK\",\"expiry\":1500566765,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gWHnaLi.MQCrSpc3uqZI.uR6dsbSv3.OAbA/VmFQFOSwYy.ilzbSy\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:06:05.349+02:00\"},\"Zb9n6Xsuv8uDoz0UgREIvA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$WsH4tTHx3t7olJwdNNekG.zxCo2.5CRPYvTJQN1muKZnBeKD3z8Eq\",\"expiry\":1500569836,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$cK1y.pzug.PpTi53/bxMG.A.h8idbngy1G4G07fke1YKCCBqmxBXK\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:57:16.971+02:00\"},\"cqBp_VyXAgnwQaboLddNqA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aHpZo34C3BOgBCRuMZXA8u8Dm9eQbaZBncMfAUExcJnSzBgXoHWta\",\"expiry\":1500567653,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$N9la9pzAkmJotIf/nVmx6uOmHVBhYjagMTKhCb/52hVFhlwhbotz2\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:20:55.382+02:00\"},\"-1YucaseQui9xTM8joV1bA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ZTYVkIcPjl7VDi45RkkB3uvZLM8I5GYgNnm1Go602T4AUP40TWmIK\",\"expiry\":1500570282,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$Blv8cg7Q0Nq2l9mYoWpDe./W4Bmqw6Tadvh0rb63PQTJ9O8BbWBD.\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:04:42.416+02:00\"},\"r37dOyCTPEPPF0E3n4MJAw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$gb8ERl211K2HcHe6X1SX1ex2yQ4L9JqJQF5dLM.faEUeIgW0v1Sma\",\"expiry\":1500573270,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$ol47NlxNVlWTOc6LuOQHNuaFJOpxO/I8huGuB/1wwiFT3XjCNFKPW\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:54:30.343+02:00\"},\"7FWoXqZgN7WDmkOIgonMDA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$K4gLINjrtFvEbmGG9wM88OfMbJF3y4mw39U8Y/io9awRTBtLNhyTa\",\"expiry\":1500573600,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gucXe2txI3XT5bCfqP5QfegS.c.DAJLAzemgxm1YSbyGXutt01b02\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:00:01.178+02:00\"},\"pUk1lCvCOmCyxfFKv4Tmnw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$U7RL54MKDFPQCq/R7uhjDeafKtqpj9X1zCAk1kWmIjYkWUeaCpfcS\",\"expiry\":1500574025,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$p0Unq1sHVowseikwok7HqOVw/wAry/K1RZHUrzL0.OMdVQ1T.cYPS\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:07:05.733+02:00\"},\"Zpq95Nuc5UOP6PEK4nDCjQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$C5f/nxd35s/6HmewsWmMU.aB4GHn7Hh6NTJEWR3xxzAwA4iHKDZlC\",\"expiry\":1500575385,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$yjQGp/F.dHBipka.DHheaeSHhMDyPVukLhxhiE4V79BsJrytIDfOi\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:29:45.673+02:00\"},\"2vGGRC7gOCFTBiYSkMCfXQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ykxrUsRX0yZOtLW03cbqyezhVQ4fqnLHBrVIgilIaxhp0d8hqCE0m\",\"expiry\":1500618218,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$dEf3s9O.Upz4cG0xAwEOC.Axlw70Xm9fsy9f2UP5iqffGT1BPLEze\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T08:23:38.253+02:00\"},\"kkuI52Vq05TOCSVBgHGWHA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$XDPo.nKeRj.blboiVey8u.sh7vlubmRo5k/B86l5AvL3ZJw.0yjhG\",\"expiry\":1500621303,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$RkvthXkouoosD2l3OVFNqetvlfG686Ltac1TAlO9to0SMOpSgpKue\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T09:15:03.323+02:00\"},\"DqpFWUYwTyHsq0z5V-H3sA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$.Ssm5ZSlVL/4Wr3FOUkOTOs/xP/V/vxGS01.zwe.5ictpoOD7xsHi\",\"expiry\":1500621764}}', `updated_at` = '2017-07-07 07:22:44' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `sign_in_count` = 23, `current_sign_in_at` = '2017-07-07 07:22:44', `last_sign_in_at` = '2017-07-07 07:00:58' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `tokens` = '{\"Zb9n6Xsuv8uDoz0UgREIvA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$WsH4tTHx3t7olJwdNNekG.zxCo2.5CRPYvTJQN1muKZnBeKD3z8Eq\",\"expiry\":1500569836,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$cK1y.pzug.PpTi53/bxMG.A.h8idbngy1G4G07fke1YKCCBqmxBXK\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:57:16.971+02:00\"},\"cqBp_VyXAgnwQaboLddNqA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aHpZo34C3BOgBCRuMZXA8u8Dm9eQbaZBncMfAUExcJnSzBgXoHWta\",\"expiry\":1500567653,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$N9la9pzAkmJotIf/nVmx6uOmHVBhYjagMTKhCb/52hVFhlwhbotz2\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T18:20:55.382+02:00\"},\"-1YucaseQui9xTM8joV1bA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ZTYVkIcPjl7VDi45RkkB3uvZLM8I5GYgNnm1Go602T4AUP40TWmIK\",\"expiry\":1500570282,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$Blv8cg7Q0Nq2l9mYoWpDe./W4Bmqw6Tadvh0rb63PQTJ9O8BbWBD.\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:04:42.416+02:00\"},\"r37dOyCTPEPPF0E3n4MJAw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$gb8ERl211K2HcHe6X1SX1ex2yQ4L9JqJQF5dLM.faEUeIgW0v1Sma\",\"expiry\":1500573270,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$ol47NlxNVlWTOc6LuOQHNuaFJOpxO/I8huGuB/1wwiFT3XjCNFKPW\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T19:54:30.343+02:00\"},\"7FWoXqZgN7WDmkOIgonMDA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$K4gLINjrtFvEbmGG9wM88OfMbJF3y4mw39U8Y/io9awRTBtLNhyTa\",\"expiry\":1500573600,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$gucXe2txI3XT5bCfqP5QfegS.c.DAJLAzemgxm1YSbyGXutt01b02\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:00:01.178+02:00\"},\"pUk1lCvCOmCyxfFKv4Tmnw\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$U7RL54MKDFPQCq/R7uhjDeafKtqpj9X1zCAk1kWmIjYkWUeaCpfcS\",\"expiry\":1500574025,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$p0Unq1sHVowseikwok7HqOVw/wAry/K1RZHUrzL0.OMdVQ1T.cYPS\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:07:05.733+02:00\"},\"Zpq95Nuc5UOP6PEK4nDCjQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$C5f/nxd35s/6HmewsWmMU.aB4GHn7Hh6NTJEWR3xxzAwA4iHKDZlC\",\"expiry\":1500575385,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$yjQGp/F.dHBipka.DHheaeSHhMDyPVukLhxhiE4V79BsJrytIDfOi\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-06T20:29:45.673+02:00\"},\"2vGGRC7gOCFTBiYSkMCfXQ\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$ykxrUsRX0yZOtLW03cbqyezhVQ4fqnLHBrVIgilIaxhp0d8hqCE0m\",\"expiry\":1500618218,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$dEf3s9O.Upz4cG0xAwEOC.Axlw70Xm9fsy9f2UP5iqffGT1BPLEze\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T08:23:38.253+02:00\"},\"kkuI52Vq05TOCSVBgHGWHA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$XDPo.nKeRj.blboiVey8u.sh7vlubmRo5k/B86l5AvL3ZJw.0yjhG\",\"expiry\":1500621303,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$RkvthXkouoosD2l3OVFNqetvlfG686Ltac1TAlO9to0SMOpSgpKue\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T09:15:03.323+02:00\"},\"DqpFWUYwTyHsq0z5V-H3sA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$vaeWtFcZiwA85dtRtwhRj.Ko0WMS.9gL0eDdhfTVoIIvIT7aN8BEy\",\"expiry\":1500621764,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$.Ssm5ZSlVL/4Wr3FOUkOTOs/xP/V/vxGS01.zwe.5ictpoOD7xsHi\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-07T09:22:44.824+02:00\"}}' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 235ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
```

So to me it looks like the user is sign in the application, but devise is not returning anything.

//EDIT//
I've cloned https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token-example and that's working locally. Although I still get the 'Unpermitted parameter: session' error. It looks like there's something wrong with my front-end though. Going to investigate and post the result later.

Comment: You got `Unpermitted parameter: :session`. Post your controller code

Comment: I mean `DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController` code

Comment: I have no such file. It also doesn't say anything about a sessionscontroller in this documentation: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Comment: I cloned the project: https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token-example and it's working locally, so I'm going to check the differences and see if there's something not covered in the tutorial.